# Print subsequence which have sum 0 in Python list

Tags: python, list, subsequence

I have a Numpy array (arr) and want to print all subsequences such that sum of values in the subsequence equals to zero. I have a code but in this I get subArrays.

```
def findSubArrays(arr,n):
    
    hashMap = {}

    out = []

    sum1 = 0
    for i in range(n):

        sum1 += arr[i]
        if sum1 == 0:
            out.append((0, i))
        al = []
        if sum1 in hashMap:
            al = hashMap.get(sum1)
            for it in range(len(al)):
                out.append((al[it] + 1, i))
        al.append(i)
        hashMap[sum1] = al
    return out


def printOutput(output):
    for i in output:
        print ("Subarray found from Index " +
        str(i[0]) + " to " + str(i[1]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [6, 3, -1, -3, 4, -2,
            2, 4, 6, -12, -7]
    n = len(arr)
    out = findSubArrays(arr, n)
    if (len(out) == 0):
        print ("No subarray exists")
    else:
        printOutput (out)
```

This code returns the subArrays which will have sum equals zero. But I want subsequences with size of the output subsequence greater than 2 and less than 7. I want to get the index of values in those subsequences.

Comment: If you wanna go deep, this sounds like a decent issue for a genetic algorithm, BUt that might be too complex, also You didnt share you code attempt. So please edit the question and add more details

Comment: You need to give more details, limits, examples, objective… it seems that the combinations can quickly explode.

Comment: how long is your input array? depending on the length you can attempt some algorithms or discard them. Then, do you want to find all the solutions or some? There's a huge difference between a perfect solution and a good enough solution.

Comment: length of my input array is around 50 and want to get output subsequence with len between 2 to 7.